# Action on succeful XMLHttprequest Form POST not triggering, but I do receive e-mail

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

So another day, another problem. I'm rewriting my website from jQuery to vanilla ES6 and i have a problem with my form. Previously I was triggering a different action on jQuery `.done()` and on `.error()` and it worked just fine, but now my specified action triggers on `xhr.addEventListener("error", e => { code }`, but not on `xhr.addEventListener("load ", e => { code }`.

Here is the code that I have:

```
form.addEventListener("submit", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  for (let i = inputFail.length; i--; ) {
    inputFail[i].remove();
  }
  if (validateForm()) {
    const formData = new FormData(form);
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.addEventListener("error", e => {
      console.log("error");
      const failPL = "Nie udało się, spróbuj jeszcze raz.";
      const failENG = "Something went wrong, please try again.";
      const postFail = document.createElement("div");
      const failText = document.createElement("p");
      postFail.classList.add("form__fail");
      postFail.classList.add("fade-in-out");
      if (langPL.classList.contains("button--lang--active")) {
        failText.innerText = failPL;
        postFail.appendChild(failText);
        form.appendChild(postFail);
      } else {
        failText.innerText = failENG;
        postFail.appendChild(failText);
        form.appendChild(postFail);
      }
      setTimeout(() => {
        postFail.remove();
      }, 5000)
    });
    xhr.addEventListener("load ", e => {
      console.log("success");
      const successPl = 'Dziękuję za wiadomość!';
      const successENG = 'Thank you for your message!';
      const postSuccess = document.createElement("div");
      const successText = document.createElement("p");
      postSuccess.classList.add("form__success");
      postSuccess.classList.add("fade-in-out");
      form.reset();
      if (langPL.classList.contains("button--lang--active")) {
        successText.innerText = successPl;
        postSuccess.appendChild(successText);
        form.appendChild(postSuccess);
      } else {
        successText.innerText = successENG;
        postSuccess.appendChild(successText);
        form.appendChild(postSuccess);
      }
      setTimeout(() => {
        postSuccess.remove();
      }, 5000)
    });
    xhr.open("POST", form.action);
    xhr.send(formData);
  }
})
```

So basically when I turn off the internet connection and sumbit the form, an error event is fired and a nice, red div with error text is appended to the form letting a user know that the POST has failed and he/she should try again. I want to have a similar thing with `form.reset()` after succesfully submiting it, but it just doesn't work. I do get an e-mail from the form so it is working, but it seems that the "load" event doesn't fire. I've also tried with `xhr.status === 200` and `xhr.readyState === 4` but again, no luck. So - what is the exact equivalent of jquery `.done()` form method?

I will appreciate all the help, but please do not suggest sticking to jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but not on `xhr.addEventListener("load ", e => { code }.`

You have an extra space there. Change to

`xhr.addEventListener("load"`

Note that you could iterate automatically over your inputFails via

```
inputFail.forEach(element => element.remove());
```

Your current `for` loop's syntax has issues, too. (the second part is the while condition, not the incrementer/decrementer)

Also, don't use IE's not-so-reliable `.innerText`, use the standard method `.textContent` instead.

You can simplify this

```
setTimeout(() => {
  postSuccess.remove();
}, 5000)
```

to

```
setTimeout(postSuccess.remove, 5000);
```

since it's a standalone function, and so can be passed as a parameter itself.